# Zip file is getting corrupted after downloading from server in nodejs

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

```
var fileUrl = "http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/bootstrap.zip";
var output = "bootstrap.zip";
request({url: fileUrl, encoding: null}, function(err, resp, body) {
  if(err) throw err;
  fs.writeFile(output, body, function(err) {
    console.log("file written!");
  });
});
```

in this code we download zip file as zip and supported.but not to support or the file may corrupted for downloading some other format as jpg,csv...

Comment: You should be checking `resp.statusCode` and `resp.headers['content-type']` instead of assuming you're getting what you requested.

Comment: It writes the body of response to a file. But I opened the file and found it an HTML file. The `fileUrl` didn't not respond with zip.

Comment: ok.. could anyone suggest just concept of downloading all files in zip format using nodejs..